# Can't get XDEBUG , WEBGRIND to work on windows

Tags: php, xdebug, webgrind

I'm trying to use Webgrind. 
Who can help me on track.
I have the following situation.
Windows-7 64 bit
APACHE - 2.4.9
PHP - 5.5.12 with
XDEBUG 2.4.0 and 
Webgrind 1.3 (latest version) installed in: 
http://localhost/webgrind/

For testing purposes I have a very small PHP script executing

`phpinfo();`

I don't get any files in my "D:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp" directory.
So I also don't see anything in my "http://localhost/webgrind/"  window.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thnx.

**Php.ini**

```
;XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

**webgrind\config.php**

```
static $storageDir  = 'D:/wamp/www/webgrind/tmp';
static $profilerDir = 'D:/wamp/www/webgrind/tmp';
```

Comment: When you look with your phpinfo(), your xdebug configuration is the same as your Php.ini file ?

Comment: I think so, yes.

`This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans`

The exact DLL was downloaded after the advise on the XDEBUG site. There I had to upload the PHPINFO() output.

Comment: What does it say for in your phpinfo for xdebug `profiler_enable` ?

Comment: `xdebug.profiler_enable On On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value no value no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp c:\wamp\www\webgrind\tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%t.%p cachegrind.out.%t.%p
`